# openpyxl giving memory error while updating sheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to update exsting sheet in excel using openpyxl and i am getting below error.

File "src\lxml\xmlerror.pxi", line 87, in lxml.etree._LogEntry._setError
MemoryError:

My excel file is of 27MB size.

please find the code i am using below.

```
evidenceworkbook = load_workbook("Inforce_Fire_Validation.xlsx")
sheet_data = evidenceworkbook['Source']
poldata_D2 = sheet_data['A7']
poldata_D2.value = "testing D2"
evidenceworkbook.save("Inforce_Fire_Validation.xlsx")
```

I tried using write_only but as per my analysis this is for creating new excel with large data.

Comment: If you really need to edit large files then you will need to have enough memory on your computer to do so. If you are only interested in editing data read using `read_only=True` and write to a new Workbook using `write_only=True`. Note that this will mean charts, images, etc. are lost.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use the Optimized reader (link - https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html).
While loading a workbook pass `read_only=True`

```
wb = load_workbook(file_path, read_only=True)
```

Comment: As per my analysis this read_only true is for reading the data from excel. I tried using it it is giving me "TypeError: Workbook is read-only". I want to update the existing sheet.

Comment: @manjari Have to tried this 
wb = load_workbook(file_path, write_only=True)

Comment: Yes Ishwar, it is throwing error as 'TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'write_only'"

Comment: evidenceworkbook = load_workbook("file_example_XLSX_5000.xlsx", read_only=False)

Can you try this.@manjari

Comment: i am getting memory error with read_only=False

Comment: @manjari I would suggest you to use https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/